# Trying to set session data when logging in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am looking to retrieve the users details and set them to session variables so I can use them across the site once the user is logged in (providing the login is successful).

The issue I find is now I'm using prepared statements if I select anything more and then the username in the select statement it fails.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, email, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

$username = $_POST['ulogin'];
$password = $_POST['upassword'];

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $email, $username, $password);

// Fetch & check user details
if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    // Check if password matches
    if (password_verify($_POST['upassword'], $password)) {

        // Set the session data here by getting the username, email, id etc..

        header('Location: ../index.php');

    } else{
        echo "Password is wrong!";
    }

} else{
    echo "Wrong username";
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

If I include say id or email in the select it breaks.

I am also trying to get the user data form the database but if I try to bind data from the table to a session variable it doesn't pass it through.

Error when adding more columns to select in the statement:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in...

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? That doesn't give us anything to go on. Actual errors?

Comment: Sorry I know that wasn't helpful, I have updated the question

Comment: Unless you're not showing us something, you are binding one variable (`username`) so you should not be getting this error. If you add another column to the query it should not fail with that error. Are you trying to bind additional values?

Comment: @PhpDude I suspect you added another placeholder ?

Comment: nowhere in your code did you include `bind_result()`. I'm suspecting not enough or too many variables passed in it which doesn't match your SELECT'ed columns. Take this as a temporary "answer" to this question; I know I'm right about this. And watch someone pop an answer using my comment, just you watch.

Comment: @PhpDude are you sure is that all your code?

Comment: So show us the query where you add another column

Comment: im new to prepared statements so this is just killing me trying to understand

Comment: @Fred-ii- "nowhere in your code did you include bind_result()." could you explain to me what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the manual on `bind_result()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

> *"When mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called to fetch data, the MySQL client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the specified variables var1, ...."*
>
> *"Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch(). Depending on column types bound variables can silently change to the corresponding PHP type."*

So, if you added, or reduced the amount of variables in that function and it didn't match the number of columns in `SELECT`, then that's the problem.

By the way, you should add a `exit;` after your header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue to execute further down below.

Comment: right, ok so what I did is added more variables in the `$stmt->bind_result($id, $email, $username, $password);` and then in the select statement included id and email, how do I access those and set them as sessions variables?

Comment: @PhpDude you need to use the same amount of columns in `SELECT` as you do for `bind_result()`.

Comment: I have done that, so I have 4 variables and 4 columns selected... Im just struggling to fetch say the userid and username and set it to a session variable.

Comment: @PhpDude You're going to have to update your question with the full code you're using and shown "exactly" how it's outlined. BUT. do NOT overwrite your existing question, but marked as an additional edit "under" your original question, stating something like: *"This is my full code that I am now using..."*.

Comment: There you go, I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @PhpDude I tried your code and got back success. Make sure all columns do exist. Yet, what I tested was slightly different than yours as I replaced `if (password_verify($_POST['upassword'], $password)) {` with `if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){` and also added `$stmt->store_result();` under `$stmt->execute();`. I suggest you check for errors against the query with `mysqli_error($conn)` and use error reporting, making sure all have value. I'm afraid there isn't much else I can add to all this, sorry.

Comment: Awesome, your checking was brilliant for me to correct it. I understand now what is happening exactly. I just need to do a while loop and use the variables set in order for me to pass them along as session data. Im such a doink

Comment: @PhpDude Hey, it happens so don't be so hard on yourself :-) we all passed though that wringer before and myself as well (yep!). I'm glad this all got cleared up, *cheers!*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135803/discussion-between-phpdude-and-fred-ii).